# Without the first line table

Tags: javascript, html

Help

```
for (var i = 1; i<mo.rows.length;i++) {
    mo.rows[i].cells[1].innerText=na.rows[i % na.rows.length].cell[0].innerText 
}
```

[image]

Comment: Help what, exactly?

Comment: See the attached photo

Comment: That image is just random words and arrows. What on Earth are you asking?

Comment: Asking not to the first line listed Located in a table na

Comment: I think when he creates his name column in the right table, he doesn't want "name" to be in the table. I think?

Comment: Why not have "Name" manually set into the `table header` in `mo` and not include a `table header` in `na`?

Comment: Please be clear in describing your problem in a precise way.

Comment: Don't use `.innerText`, it's not standard and won't work in Firefox. Use `.textContent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must divide by lenght-1 and takes the value from line number 1. Thats why you must substract 1 from length and add 1 to position

```
for (var i = 1; i<mo.rows.length;i++) {
    mo.rows[i].cells[1].innerText=na.rows[i % (na.rows.length-1)+1].cell[0].innerText 
}
```

Comment: Thank
Thank
Thank
 Adjust this Maridi